# Only return output from targeted modules

Tags: terraform

I have a tf file that calls a bunch of modules:

```
variable "myvar" {}

module "mod1" {
  arg = "${var.myvar}"
  paramblah = "sldkfjsldkfj"
  source = "...my git repo..."
}

module "mod2" {
  arg = "${var.myvar}"
  paramblah = "sdifjsdfssldkfjsldkfj"
  source = "...my git repo..."
}

module "mod3" {
  arg = "${var.myvar}"
  paramblah = "qiejiqjd"
  source = "...my git repo..."
}

output "myoutput" {
  value = ["${module.mod1.modsOutput}",
    "${module.mod2.modsOutput}",
    "${module.mod3.modsOutput}"]
}
```

Sometimes I'll target a single module in the tf file:

```
terraform apply -var myvar=sdfsdfsdf -target='module.mod2'
```

Is there a way to have `terraform output` only return the output from the last module I targeted? Right now if I run `terraform output myoutput` it returns the output of all the modules I defined in the list.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with only outputting the values from the last module targeted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to break them out in individual outputs:

```
variable "myvar" {}

module "mod1" {
  arg = "${var.myvar}"
  paramblah = "sldkfjsldkfj"
  source = "...my git repo..."
}

module "mod2" {
  arg = "${var.myvar}"
  paramblah = "sdifjsdfssldkfjsldkfj"
  source = "...my git repo..."
}

module "mod3" {
  arg = "${var.myvar}"
  paramblah = "qiejiqjd"
  source = "...my git repo..."
}

output "myoutput" {
  value = ["${module.mod1.modsOutput}",
    "${module.mod2.modsOutput}",
    "${module.mod3.modsOutput}"]
}

output "mod1" { value = "${module.mod1.modsOutput}"}
output "mod2" { value = "${module.mod2.modsOutput}"}
output "mod3" { value = "${module.mod3.modsOutputs}"}
```

this seems to work, but is there a way to make it more dynamic? instead of having to redundantly plug them in individually?